# Javascript, array concat adds Windows Object to a result array, however it doesn't work for Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I was trying some javascript and found strange behavior. 
After making reference to an array.concat function and calling it the result of it now has Window Object in it(Crome Browser, Firefox does not run the code).

What could be the problem?

Here is the code:

```
var data = [];
var c = data.concat;
var someArray = ["a"];
var data2 = c(someArray);
console.log(data2);
```

You can try it http://jsfiddle.net/Dhf9S/3/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you want to make a function `c` that's basically a shortcut for `concat`? Is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `data.concat` without setting the scope to `data`, so it runs in the scope of the global object, which in this case is `window`.

If you want to concatenate `data` and `someArray`, you would need to use `call` to set the scope of the `concat` function:

```
var data2 = c.call(data, someArray);
```

To create a shortcut to `data.concat`, you can use `bind` to always run it in the scope of `data`:

```
var c = data.concat.bind(data);
var data2 = c(someArray);
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to post the `bind` alternative, otherwise you need to specify the context every time.

Comment: shouldn't c = data.concat already have the data scope as default?

Comment: `data.concat` is actually a pointer to `Array.prototype.concat`, which runs in the global scope unless called on an instance.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my the noobish questions. :)